# Failed to connect react to backend node js server express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am a beginner and I am trying to understand the PORT and server side connection with react js.
Ive been reading an article and trying to connect react js to node express.
**React port is http://localhost:5174**
And in the article they list steps how to connect backend to React and I have done the same but it didn't work any one can help me please ?

// App.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Task from "./Task";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  //Value of Input
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const addTodos = (e) => {
    if (val == "") return;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, val]);
    setVal("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5174/message")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setMessage(data.message));
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((_, key) => key !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/** On change values*/}
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
          value={val}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, key) => (
          <Task todo={todo} key={key} myKey={key} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      {message + " Iam from the backend"}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//Server -> server.js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/server", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello from server!" });
});

app.listen(5174, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 5174.`);
});



PS: All the dependencies are installed
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

Comment: hi. this endpoint 'http://localhost:5174/message' is not defined in your Node.js code

Comment: Thanks for replying how i can define it please ?

Comment: You have defined one endpoint called '/server' in your code. So similarly you need to define another endpoint called '/message'. Based on your requirement it can be either GET or POST. Accordingly make changes in React js code

Comment: I defined it but the message still haven't shown in React                app.get("/server", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello from server!" });
});

app.get("/message", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello from server!" });
});

Comment: are you getting a response from the server? Please do a console.log(data) in your fetch callback. Also please restart the server.

Comment: .then((res) => res.json() && console.log(res)) im getting something and i restarted the server the error is :      Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: can you please post your package.json file in your question. Have you configured any proxy in the same? Please check this link https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252828/discussion-between-jj-ammar-and-inkredusk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed over chat, below is the solution to the problem

First, you need to define an endpoint as follows in your server side code:

```
app.get("/message", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "This is a test message from server!" });
});
```

Then you can define a `proxy` in your React app that points to your server as follows:

```
// client/package.json

...
"proxy": "http://localhost:5134",
...
```

Next, you need to update your `fetch` method call the `/message` endpoint and it should work fine. Please ensure the server is up and running.

Reference link - [Create react app with node backend](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/)